# How to specify the scope of a snippet between a PHP or a HTML file?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

It seems that when examining the scope of a PHP file, whose extension is `.php`, and whose syntax is correctly recognised as `PHP`, Sublime will still report it as `text.html.basic` (among others). This makes my HTML snippet always execute in it.

Since what I want is to make a snippet that has `todo` as its `tabTrigger`, to insert a commented out tag, obviously i need it to be different for the different filetypes (`<!-- -->` or `/* */`). But this way, the `<!-- -->` comment gets inserted into the PHP file...

Is there an extra detail i'm missing, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP syntax in Sublime Text is an extension of the HTML syntax, meaning all HTML is valid in a `.php` file, plus the extra `<?php … ?>` tag. If your cursor is in a `.php` file, but outside the `<?php` tag, the scope will be `embedding.php text.html.basic` and comments should take the `<!-- … -->` HTML form.

Once you're inside that PHP tag, you now have an additional scope of `source.php`. Comments now should use PHP comments `/* … */` and/or `// …`.

For your snippet, just set the scope as `source.php`, and it should only trigger inside actual PHP code.

If you want your snippet to trigger only in HTML, and **not** in PHP, set the source to `text.html.basic -source.php`.

<sup>**Note** This is all true in the most recent version of Sublime Text 3 (3.2.2, Build 3211). The PHP syntax was entirely refactored earlier, so this may not work correctly with earlier builds. If you haven't upgraded, now is a great time!</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In side your PHP tags, you need to use the `source.php`, while outside of the tags it's `text.html.php`. You likely want something like this:

**PHP**

```xml
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[/* TODO $1 */]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>todo</tabTrigger>
  <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

**HTML (PHP)**

```xml
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[<!-- TODO $1 -->]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>todo</tabTrigger>
  <scope>text.html.php</scope>
</snippet>
```